# What is the maximum width of a Facebook game page?

Tags: facebook

I read it was going to be changed to 520px, but I keep seeing pages that are new that are the older 760px width. Is it safe to build at the wider width still or should we be building at 520px?

Anyone know if you can still design for 760px width? If not, what's the new width?

Answer (score 4):

Based on experience, and according to current Facebook documentation, it is either 760px or fluid width:

> The canvas chrome is 760px width by default but you can set it to be a Fluid Canvas so that it is left aligned and takes up the full width and height of the user browser.

Source: [Apps on Facebook.com - Facebook Developers, Getting Started](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)